# Object oriented - Method vs. variable access

Tags: class, oop, object, methods

I have heard that using a method to access a value is much better than simply calling the value of the variable itself. For example, using a bank account class, it would be better to use.

```
myAccount.getBalance()
```

than simply accessing the variable directly using

```
myAccount.balance
```

What is the purpose of doing this method, as the second seems more direct and requires less characters to complete.

Comment: Many reasons - error handling, encapsulation ...

Comment: As usual, it depends. Many of the answers below assume that the value of `balance` is accessed externally, in which case you should encapsulate its access within a getter. If you use `balance` only from within the class, access it directly; in other  words, if you need to present an accessor to client/collaborator classes, encapsulate it (make the member variable inaccessible and make the accessor method accessible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is better if you value the idea of encapsulation and information hiding.

More direct?  Maybe.  But indirection is exactly why the method is usually better.  What if `getBalance()` really means a complex calculation that draws on several external services?  Users don't have to worry about that complexity; all they know is that they've called a method.  It's hidden behind the object's interface.

Object oriented programming brings four ideas to the table:

1. Abstract data types
2. Encapsulation and information hiding
3. Inheritance
4. Polymorphism

Don't be so quick to throw away the fundamentals so lightly.

I'll put it back on you: What do you save by going after values?  Typing?  Keystrokes are cheap.  Performance?  Please.  No good reason to go right after variables that way.

Answer (score 1):

Less no of characters is not the goal, the goal is to have manageable code, with more control.

When you access a class variable directly, you override all the business logic of that class. What if the balance is not calculated yet? What if its not validated? If you encapsulate that data (declaring the variable private, and allow access thru a method only), you control what the calling code is receiving, and your code gets a chance to execute required business logic.

Answer (score 1):

**Method is enerally better**

A likely outcome related to your example, what if your account class was later adjusted to contain a list of transactions on your account and the balance not stored but calculated.  With a method, this would simply be a change within the class, saving the need to update all the parts of the system that use the balance.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you and honestly, I usually stuck at there, what is the purpose of using the methods, creating them is more hassle (not really) but still hassle than directly calling it. Actually, methods are better when you're using Encapsulation (a pillar of OOP).
**Encapsulation means** to encapsulate data from accessing by 3rd party here we call it other classes. We use private access modifier in order to restrict the access, thus we create `Setter and getters` which you can define as `Mutator/Accessor`.
Now the question is why do we use methods? **Why do we need to create them?**
The simple answer is that, `if you want to add additional check before setting the state of an object, and that's the reason we create methods for accessing the value from outside of the class or the same class doesn't matter.`
Like consider this.

```
public void setRadius(int a)
{
 if(radius>0)
 radius=a;
}
```

If you encapsulate datafields of the class, you'll have to add method for getting the value also.

You could have never done that, if you don't encapsulate and make methods of it.